# I don't see crashes on Firebase Crashlytics dashboard after update SDK to 17.0.0+ version

Tags: android, sdk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

[image: Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard]

2 weeks ago I updated Firebase Crashlytics SDK to the 17.0.0+ version and after that, I couldn't see crashes on the Crashlytics dashboard. Instead of I see the red boxed message

> "As of November 16, we are only processing crashes from the Firebase
> Crashlytics Android SDK 17.0.0+. As a result, you will not see new
> crashes in your dashboard. Learn More"

I used this doc for SDK migration - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android&authuser=4

I also used BOM instead of directly SDK link, but it didn't help me.

My app level **build.gradle** file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com...."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 51457
        versionName "2.7.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'

        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'

        exclude 'lib/arm/*'
        exclude 'lib/mips/*'
        exclude 'lib/mips64/*'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

def jwp_version = "3.13.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/optimizely/optimizely'
    }
    maven {
        url  "http://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://nativo.jfrog.io/nativo/libs-release'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Ads SKDs and libraries
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Amazon DFP
    implementation project(":DTBAndroidSDK-8.0.0")

    implementation files('libs/NexageSDK.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sourcekit-mraid.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sourcekit-vast.jar')
    implementation(group: 'net.nativo.sdk', name: 'nativo-sdk', version: '4.3.9', ext: 'aar')
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"

    // Analytics
    implementation 'com.adobe.mobile:adobeMobileLibrary:4.15.0'
    implementation 'com.comscore:android-analytics:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:5.4.1'
    implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.0'
    compile files('libs/bluekai-2.1.7.jar')

    // Misc
    implementation 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2'
    implementation(name: 'VRKit', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.38.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    // Android Support Libraries
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation  'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.github.anrwatchdog:anrwatchdog:1.4.0'

    // Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.0.0'

    // Google Firebase SDKs
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0"

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

    // JWPlayer
    implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:$jwp_version"
    implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:$jwp_version"
    implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:$jwp_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'

}
```

Comment: Please share your app-level `build.gradle`.

Comment: @DYS I added an app-level build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by simply upgrading my crashlytics library also changed JSON file
followed this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android&authuser=4

also, make sure to add a crash/bug to see the changes on the firebase console
throw RuntimeException("Test Crash") // Force a crash

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=4&platform=android#kotlin+ktx

Comment: I did these steps and it didn't help me.